# Cumulative count of unique values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, unique, union

Suppose you are collecting cards - your album is made of `n_cards` cards. Each pack you buy contains `cards_in_pack` cards, each card has the same probability to be extracted. How many packs do you need to buy in order to collect all the cards if you can't trade your doubles? Suppose you want to simulate the process. This is an obvious way to do it:

```
n_cards = 100; n_experiments = 1e4; cards_in_pack = 5;
cards = randi([1 n_cards], ceil(sqrt(n_cards)) * n_experiments * n_cards, 1, 'uint16');

tic
n_packs = zeros(n_experiments, 1);
ctrl1 = 1;
i_f = 0;
n = 0;
while ctrl1
  ctrl2 = 1;
  i1 = 0;
  while ctrl2
    i1 = i1 + 1;
    ctrl2 = numel(unique(cards((cards_in_pack * i_f + 1):(cards_in_pack * (i_f + i1))))) ~= n_cards;
  end
  n = n + 1;
  n_packs(n) = i1;
  i_f = i_f + i1;
  ctrl1 = n ~= n_experiments;
end
toc

% Average number of packs: 
mean(n_packs)
% Distribution of the number of packs necessary to complete the album
hist(n_packs, 50)

% Number of cards needed in the experiments: 
sum(n_packs) * cards_in_pack
```

This is very slow - is there a faster way to do it? Specifically: is there a fast way to calculate the cumulative count of unique values in Matlab?

Comment: Is the question specifically about Monte Carlo simulation? The _fastest_ way to find the expected number of packs would be to calculate it directly - [it's a well-understood problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: Actually it is specifically about the way you calculate a cumulative count of unique values in Matlab - the example is just an example useful for bootstrapping.

Comment: +1 Interesting question, well explained, runnable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulation can be **vectorized across experiments**. So the experiment loop is removed, and simulation time is greatly reduced.

Since each experiment may finish at different times (different number of packs required), an experiment can be in two states: *ongoing* or *finished*. The code maintains a vector of ongoing experiments (`exps_ongoing`) and a 0-1 matrix of obtained cards in each experiment (`cards_obtained`).

For each ongoing experiment, a new pack is generated and the cards contained in that pack are (over)written on `cards_obtained`. When all cards have been obtained for an ongoing experiment, that experiment is removed from `exps_ongoing`. The code ends when all experiments have finished.

```
n_cards = 100;
cards_in_pack = 5;
n_experiments = 1e4;

cards_obtained = zeros(n_cards,n_experiments);
%// will contain cards obtained in each experiment
exps_ongoing = 1:n_experiments; %// list of which experiments are ongoing
n_packs = zeros(1,n_experiments); %// will record how many packs have been used
while ~isempty(exps_ongoing)
    n_packs(exps_ongoing) = n_packs(exps_ongoing) + 1;
    %// pick one pack for each ongoing experiment
    new_cards = randi(n_cards,cards_in_pack,numel(exps_ongoing));
    %// generate pack contents for each ongoing experiment
    cards_obtained(new_cards + repmat(((exps_ongoing)-1)*n_cards,cards_in_pack,1)) = true;
    %// take note of obtained cards in each ongoing experiment. Linear indexing is used here
    exps_ongoing = setdiff(exps_ongoing,exps_ongoing(all(cards_obtained(:,exps_ongoing))));
    %// ongoing experiments for which all cards have been obtained are removed
end
disp(mean(n_packs))
```

For your input data, this reduces time by **a factor of 50** on my computer (104.36 seconds
versus 1.89 seconds, measured with `tic`, `toc`).

Comment: Thank you Luis, your solution is fast and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

OK, in this instance, it's pretty simple to simulate because the constraints are in our favour - all we need to know is when there are no cards left that we don't have. Thus we can dump the explicit uniqueness test and just count...

I'd do it something like this:

```
n_packs = zeros(n_experiments, 1, 'uint32');
for i=1:n_experiments
    collection = zeros(n_cards, 1, 'uint32');
    while nnz(collection) < n_cards
        n_packs(i) = n_packs(i) + 1;
        pack = randi(n_cards, cards_in_pack, 1, 'uint32');
        collection(pack) = collection(pack) + 1;
    end
end
```

Now I can't guarantee that that will be faster (I don't have Matlab with me to test it - there may be a bug or two as well), but It's about the simplest algorithm I can come up with, and simple code tends to be fast code. For maximum speed tweaking have a play with the data types - `uint32` may not be optimal for everything due to Matlab's internals.

Answer (score 0):

If all cards have equal probability, you can use this simple approach I took for a [similar problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48396/how-often-do-you-have-to-roll-a-6-sided-dice-to-obtain-every-number-at-least-onc): open lots and lots of packs at once, and then check how many you would have needed to open.

```
n_cards = 100; n_experiments = 1e4; cards_in_pack = 5;
nPacks=zeros(n_experiments);
for i=1:n_experiments,
   %# assume it is never going to take you >1500000 cards
   r=randi(n_cards,1500000,1);
   %# since R2013a, unique returns the first occurrence
   %# for earlier versions, take the minimum of x
   %# and subtract it from the total array length
   [~,x]=unique(r); 
   nPacks(i,1)=ceil(max(x)/cards_in_pack);
end
```

Comment: I doubt this is really faster than the OP, unless you very finely tune that `1500000` value